# How can I switch between fglrx and ati drivers?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, ati, fglrx

How can I switch between fglrx and ati (open source) drivers without uninstalling fglrx?
The thing is I'm using FGLRX on a daily basis, because it's better for movies--OS driver displays annoying horizontal line while playing movies. FGLRX also does this, but it's less visible. That's only disadvantage of OS driver.

When I want to plug in external monitor with different resolution than my laptop's LCD I have to use open source driver, because FGLRX can't display two different resolutions at the same time.

I can uninstall FGLRX, but it's rather inconvenient to do this all the time. I've noticed that when I'm using FGLRX there is xorg.conf file and when I uninstall it, then the file is missing.

So my question is how to switch between them? It'll be perfect if I could do this without restarting my computer either.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, laptop/netbook MSI U250.

Answer (score 2):

In theory it's possible: first, you should modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, I think you need to modify things in the "Device" section (well, Xorg nowdays works fine without xorg.conf, as you noted too, so the other solution is rename xorg.conf so X won't use it).

But it's only the half part of the story, the other part is the kernel driver. I would "blacklist" fglrx as a kernel module, so it won't be load, when you don't need it: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I don't have a setup for ATI card in this way, but I have similar for nvidia, to switch between nvidia's binary driver and nouveau (open source driver for nvidia cards).

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately you cannot switch between open and closed source graphic drivers as they need to install kernel modules.

If you need different settings you may consider a dual boot setup.

Comment: Oh, why? Kernel modules can be loaded/removed run-time without reboot. Even you can blaklist them, so it won't be loaded even if it's there somewhere in /lib/modules/.... etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy solution that should work with ATI :

**You need to backup your /etc/X11/xorg.conf**

After that, if you delete xorg.conf and restart you'll start on open source drivers, and if you restore it and restart you'll start on ATI Catalyst drivers.

*The risk is minimal here but when dealing with xorg.conf make sure you know how to restore it in command line in case Xorg don't start*